# How to save PCM to Opus in C++ (Float*)

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to save my audio to a Opus file.
It's held in a Float* and is in a continuous flow added (it's a loop, a constant recording).

I am able to save the file to Wave without issue, by just writing the data and rewrite the header as needed.

Opus is more complicated, i think i am able to encode it, but i have no idea how to save it, except the raw data which i can't decode.

```
        unsigned char *compressed_buffer = new (unsigned char[500]);
        if (number == 1){
            Encoder = opus_encoder_create(48000, 2, OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO, 0);
        }
        int u = opus_encode_float(Encoder, mixBuffer.Array(), 480, compressed_buffer, 500);

        float *frame = new (float[480 * 2]);
        out.open("test.opus", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
        out.write((const char*)compressed_buffer, u);
        out.close();
```

mixBuffer.Array() = Float* containing 10ms of 32bit float Stereo each loop.

number = 1 only first run, so the Encoder isn't remade in the loop.

I am pretty sure i am way off, but i must be doing something right i guess.

Answer (score 0):

`.opus` files are actually `ogg` containers and not raw Opus data

see current draft: http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-codec-oggopus-03.txt

Comment: I am just saving it as .Opus for test, it's not even playable, i only write the data in compressed_buffer, and i have no idea if that's correct or not:(

Comment: yes, the data you want is what is output from `opus_encode_float` into the compressed buffer.

Comment: Ah well that's good, so what i am doing is correct?
But how am i supposed to save it. I need to write a header, i thought it would be built in the Opus API, but seems not.

Comment: the Opus API is only a codec.  you can make your own custom storage with headers and whatever frame packaging you want, or use a standard like the `ogg` container i suggested.

Comment: Well, i just want to be able to play the file. Currently as you see, i write the encoded data. How can i turn that to an ogg container?

Comment: use the specification i referenced and write that format, or use an sdk like libogg: http://xiph.org/downloads/

Comment: Don't understand that specification at all, it shows nothing compared to: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ , checked libogg, not really sure about it, nothing there that allows saving to an .ogg container that i can find:(

Comment: here's another link that may help you: https://wiki.xiph.org/OggOpus you're going to have to do some learning on this.